# React: how to pass / populate specific data into a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build an easily maintainable and consistent layout component for team member biographies that are spread across multiple individual pages such as:

```
JohnDoe.JS
JaneDoe.Js
JonathanDoe.Js
```

I want to map a specific set of data onto a prebuild component, that is then placed on the individual pages.

John would receive the dataset with the ID of '1', Jane with the ID of '2.

This is the data to be passed into the component:

```
      {
    id: '1',  
    link: 'john-doe',
    name: 'John Doe',
    alt: 'John Doe',
    title: 'Managing Director',
    bio: 'works with retail and consumer-goods companies to guide growth, commercial and operational transformations'}
  },

  {
    id: '2',  
    link: 'jane-doe',
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    alt: 'Jane Doe',
    title: 'Operations Director',
    bio: 'works with retail and consumer-goods companies to guide growth, commercial and operational transformations'},
```

This is the reusable component called TeamBio.js:

```
<div className="flex flex-wrap">

    
  <div className="w-full md:w-1/2 h-screen overflow-hidden order-last lg:order-first md:order-first">      
  <div className="flex h-screen">
  <div class="m-auto max-w-3xl px-5">

    {TeamData.map((item, index) => {
      return (
          <div>
            <h1 className="text-3xl xs:text-2xl md:text-3xl lg:text-5xl xl:text-6xl mb-5">{item.name}</h1>
            <p className="text-xl leading-10 uppercase mb-5 text-gray-700">{item.title}</p>
            <p className="text-xl leading-10 mb-5">{item.bio}</p>
            </div>     
      );
    })}

 </div>
 </div>
</div>

  <div className="bg-dsent-green w-full md:w-1/2 h-screen order-first lg:order-last md:order-last">

  <img className=" object-contain h-screen w-full object-none object-bottom" src={require('{item.image}').default} data-aos="fade-up" alt="{item.alt}" />

  </div>
</div>
```

Once this component is set to populate data using:

`{TeamData.map((item, index) => {`,

Every data entry is passed into the component. The data of John, Jane, and Jonathan overlap.

How, or on which level can I apply a filtering of data such as :

`{TeamData.slice(1, 2).map((item, index) => {`

to specify the data to be passed into the component?

Comment: What do you mean the data for different team members `overlaps`? As far as I can tell, what you have in `TeamBio` is correct. Although I'd suggest you take out the content within your `.map` and create a separate component out of it. But that, again, would raise the question of content overlaping.

Comment: Thank you for your question - {TeamData.map((item, index) => {,

leads to every entry of every person of the dataset being passed into the component.